# .Find - putting variable in SearchDirection causes run-time error 13 - type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

Why does this work:

`Set rowNonBlankFound = Rows(rowToUse).Find(what:="*", after:=Cells(rowToUse, leftMostCol), LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext)`

But this doesn't:

`Dim direction As String
direction = "xlNext"
Set rowNonBlankFound = Rows(rowToUse).Find(what:="*", after:=Cells(rowToUse, leftMostCol), LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=direction)`

I get run-time error 13 - type mismatch?

Comment: Direction is an enumeration https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841198.aspx  needs to be a number or an enumeration equiv

Comment: A bit of further reading:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type

Comment: Thanks for Wiki article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SearchDirection` is not a argument of type `String`, but of type `XlSearchDirection`, you cannot pass a string to it since there is no convertion from one to the other.
`xlNext` is not identical to `"xlNext"`

Use following code:

```
Dim direction As XlSearchDirection
direction = xlNext
Set rowNonBlankFound = Rows(rowToUse).Find(what:="*", after:=Cells(rowToUse, leftMostCol), LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=direction)
```

Answer (score 0):

Direction is an enumeration [enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841198.aspx) needs to be a number or an enumeration equiv